# Calculate total price of products based on prices for each day ( ReactJS )

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist

I am thinking of a solution on how to calculate total price for each weekday, based on products that were added by user. For example, I need to take all prices from Monday from both prices arrays that are nested inside the objects of productsAddedToPackage. Product 1 and product 2 prices for monday are => 1.11 and 4.44. So, this should be equal to 5.55. Then I need to update packagePrices for Monday to become from 0.00 to 5.55. Any ideas on how to do such calculations ?

This is how my total prices for the weekdays look initially:

```
packagePrices: [
            {
                dayOfWeek: 1,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Monday',
                price: 0.00
            },
            {
                dayOfWeek: 2,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Tuesday',
                price: 0.00
            },
            {
                dayOfWeek: 3,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Wednesday',
                price: 0.00
            },
            {
                dayOfWeek: 4,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Thirsday',
                price: 0.00
            },
            {
                dayOfWeek: 5,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Friday',
                price: 0.00
            },
            {
                dayOfWeek: 6,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Saturday',
                price: 0.00
            },
            {
                dayOfWeek: 0,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Sunday',
                price: 0.00
            },
        ],
```

Here are all the products

```
    productsAddedtoPackage:[ 
    { 
        code: "S0000065"
        name: "whiskey"
        packageBundledProductType: 0
        prices: [
           {dayOfWeek: 1, dayOfWeekName: "Monday", price: 1.11, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 2, dayOfWeekName: "Tuesday", price: 2.22, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 3, dayOfWeekName: "Wednesday", price: 3.33, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 4, dayOfWeekName: "Thursday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 5, dayOfWeekName: "Friday", price: 5.55, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 6, dayOfWeekName: "Saturday", price: 6.66, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 0, dayOfWeekName: "Sunday", price: 7.77, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
        ]
        productId: "223be005-4fae-4b63-1705-08d8ffe591d2"
        quantity: 1
  },        
  { 
        code: "S0000066"
        name: "beer"
        packageBundledProductType: 0
        prices: [
           {dayOfWeek: 1, dayOfWeekName: "Monday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 2, dayOfWeekName: "Tuesday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 3, dayOfWeekName: "Wednesday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 4, dayOfWeekName: "Thursday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 5, dayOfWeekName: "Friday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 6, dayOfWeekName: "Saturday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
           {dayOfWeek: 0, dayOfWeekName: "Sunday", price: 4.44, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
        ]
        productId: "223be005-4fae-4b63-1705-08d8ffe591d2"
        quantity: 1
   }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

i will change the "package price" to accept a property can be a array of object what have price and id

```
packagePrices: [
            {
                dayOfWeek: 1,
                dayOfWeekName: 'Monday',
                purchases: [{price: 1.11, id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}, 
                {price: 4.44, 
                 id:"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],
                price: 0.00
            },
```

so everytime someone make a new purchase you can make a function to map the products and grab the Price and id and push it into the purchases array, then you only have to map in the purchase array and sum the prices